How should I ground three switches in a box with one ground wire?
There are 3 switches in a junction box. Only one switch has a ground wire.
Can I extend the current ground wire to the other two switches? Can I do this by connecting all 3 ground terminals together with ground wires?


I assume that we see a ground wire coming from one of the cables. You'll bundle three pigtails of matching wire with it using a red wire nut or other connector rated for that set of wires.
Add loops to the three and connect them to your switch ground screws, wrapping the loops clockwise.

Can I use this? https://www.amazon.com/Hillman-123109-18G-Copper-Wire/dp/B000H5OL30/ref=asc_df_B000H5OL30?mcid=6f13a2dc8e9e38c9ba9c485f27535b19&hvocijid=2750739525837805553-B000H5OL30-&hvexpln=73&tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=721245378154&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=2750739525837805553&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9008193&hvtargid=pla-2281435180298&psc=1

No. Your current wire is at least #14. It may be #12, which is required for a 20 Amp circuit. Snip off a bit and go to a hardware store. You need two feet, not 25.

is it #12 or #14?

You're going to need to put on your critical thinking hat if you're planning to do wiring in your house. This is potentially dangerous. I made it fairly clear that I can't tell, and I told you how to figure it out yourself.

Simple answer is yes.  You can add 2 pigtails to the ungrounded switches and tie all 3 together.
Use a holed wire nut to tie the 2 pigtails to the existing ground wire.  The holed nut allows you to tie all 3 wire together and still connect to the ground of the 3rd switch. Then all 3 switches are grounded.

You need three pigtails not two
